# Is there any way to embed buttons in Web to Lead Email?

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service

I have a requirement wherein, I should be able to embed a button in salesforce email which I get when I(user) create a lead from Web to Lead form. 
I should get an email with a button in it which gives me functionality to send another email to the Created Lead person.

Trigger can be a viable option but , I need to know if there is any chance to do it via email.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the way. It is simple than expected.

```
Step 1:  Create an email template with a link inside it ( anchor tag) and css ( helpful to make it look like a button) 

Step 2: redirect using anchor tag href to required URL.
This Url should hit global apex class which has the functionality to send an email.

Step 4: The email Id can be passed through the URL as parameters.
```

Thanks !